# How do I annotate a pdf file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

I'm wondering on how to mark in the pdf file and save it as a pdf.

For example page 2 of [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/mlclass-resources/docs/slides/Lecture6.pdf) pdf file, we have marking in blue. I need to know how it has been done.

[image]

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Im currently using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu (any linux distro, for that matter) the best I can recommend is [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net). Like a lot of OSS, your mileage and stability may vary, but you can always contribute to the code to make it right!

Check out [this particular section in the manual](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/manual.html#pdfannotate) for instructions on how to annotate a PDF.

I just checked and xournal is [packaged for precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xournal). So Yay! Easy install.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the software you use.
[Foxit reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) allows you do that via "Comments -> Drawing.."

It has a bunch of other capabilites via the comments, quoting Foxit website:

> A comment is a written note intended as an explanation, an
>   illustration, or a statement of fact or opinion, especially a remark
>   that expresses a personal reaction or attitude. You can type a text
>   message or add a line, circle, or other shape to make comments on PDF
>   files you are reading with Foxit Reader commenting tools. Most types
>   of comments contain a pop-up window displaying your name; date and
>   time you created the comments, and a text message. You can also edit,
>   reply, delete, and move the comments with ease. This function is quite
>   helpful to your studies and work if you have to make some notes on PDF
>   documents. Foxit Reader has the following commenting tools;
>   Annotation, Note Comments, Spell Checker, Text Markup, Text Select
>   Tool, Drawing Markup, Typewriter Tool, Adding Text Box or Callout and
>   viewing comments.

Comment: is there any linux equivalent of this software?

Comment: @Learner: Foxit is available for linux as well http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/

Comment: It just installed Foxit reader 1.1 for Ubuntu, but there is no "Comments -> Drawing" menu or tool.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can actually export annotations to PDFs in Okular (this was not possible until recently): http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html

It seems Okular has to be built with Poppler at least version 0.20. It works with Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

Use adobe acrobat professional . By using that you can edit , note , highlight and even draw and save them

Comment: any free version for linux?

Comment: Acrobat professional cannot be used on linux (exception:Wine & that mess), and the hand annotation tools are crap-tastic. Trying to write on a pdf results in a sort of illegible scrawl that scarely I can understand. There are better options.

Comment: @Maxim - Super User isn't a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a tool that uses Inkscape to annotate PDFs. It's essentially a GUI glue between qpdf and Inkscape which makes it quite easy to do what Adobe Acrobat does for instance.

https://github.com/oxplot/pdfrankenstein